# How to remove CSS class inside the DIV tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-selectors

Please help how to remove css inside of div tag?

I tried with below code for removing css for the input type inside the div tag. but its now working.

```
<style>

.removeInputBorder {
    border: none
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV" >
This is a DIV element.
<input type="text" value="shakeer"  class="removeInputBorder"/>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.remove("removeInputBorder");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Select the element with querySelector

Comment: you are targeting the wrong element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, here is a solution for addClass, removeClass, hasClass in pure javascript.

Check this page: http://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

```js
function hasClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    return el.classList.contains(className)
  else
    return !!el.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'))
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add(className)
  else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.remove(className)
  else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
    el.className=el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
  }
}
```

How to call:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('peace')
addClass(el, 'be-still')
// or
removeClass(el, 'be-still')
```

Comment: This answer also works

Answer (score 4):

You try to remove `removeInputBorder` from a div but that class is on input.

Comment: Yes, My css class will be on Input only.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: @Ssyed your code is ok if you want to remove class from the button then `element` variable should point to that button, not `myDIV`.

Comment: @Patryk Gulas- can you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: @Ssyed var element = document.getElementById('myDIV').getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

Comment: @tarqanwar- Thank you. that works for me